# Determining whether $g: [0, 2] \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Consider the function $g: [0, 2] \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with
> $$
> g(x)=\begin{cases}
> x^{2} & \text{if }x\in\mathbb{Q}\\
> 0 & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$
> I want to determine if it is Riemann integrable.

My idea is that I would divide this function up into two subintervals $[0,1]$ and $[1,2]$. Then I can argue that because $g(1)=1$ that the upper sum on the interval $[1,2]$ must be greater than $1$. The lower sum for any interval is $0$, so then I can have some partition $P = [0,1]\cup[1,2]$ which does not satisfy $U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon$. Therefore, it is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: You cannot choose just one partition to show that the function is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: I'm saying that for any partition of $[1,2]$, the upper sum must be greater than 1. Then when I look at the entire interval, there is no way that some partition can satisfy the requirement for Riemann integrability. Is that not correct?

Comment: Okay. It is true that for any partition on $[1, 2]$, the upper sum is bigger than $1$, the reason is more than $g(1)=1$ though. You have to say more on that. Also it is no need to split into $[0,1]$ and $[1, 2]$.

Comment: I don't quite understand why there is no need to split into $[0,1]$ and $[1,2]$. Since $g(1)=1$, and the length of $[1,2]$ is equal to $1$, every upper sum must be greater than $1$. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Just to make sure, how do you show that the upper sum is bigger then one?

Comment: My reasoning was in my previous comment. Is that thought process incorrect or incomplete?

Comment: Might be that is implicit but let me ask a question. Given a function $g$ on $[1,2]$ and $g(1) = 1$, is it true that the upper sum of any partition is greater than 1?

Comment: I see your point. Can we really classify a function like this as increasing or decreasing after $g(1)$?

Comment: You got the point. Though your function is not increasing or decreasing. But that's ok, as for any smaller intervals in $[1,2]$, there must be a point $x$ in this intervals such that $g(x) \geq 1$.